# How to filter database query by context information from request?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Given a model like this:

```
Product(db.Model):
    __tablename___ = 'product'

    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=40))
    description = db.Column(db.String(length=8000))
    language = db.Column(db.String(length=2))
```

The idea being a "product" entry is created once per language, where language is something like `en` or `fr`.

I would like to avoid to be forced to explicity filter queries by language in all view functions, so instead of this:

```
products = Product.query.filter_by(language=request.headers['lang']).filter_by(name='something').all()
```

I want this:

```
products = Product.query.filter_by(name='something').all()
```

With the language filtering part done automagically.

How would I go about this, how can I achieve this most cleanly, and without rewriting a figurative trillion existing queries to become language-aware?

Comment: You could use an extended `Query` class which by default inspects the entity list and includes required filtering. Check the Flask-SQLAlchemy [API documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/) for how to provide such. Soft deletes is a similar concept and you might find something interesting, if you search for that.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks! I'll check it out